# Why is this integral for a uniform electric field of a charged plate not evaluating correctly?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, integration

I have spent the past two and a half hours attempting to understand why the electric field on either side of an infinitely sized charged plate is uniform. I get it conceptually, in that as a point moves farther away from the plate, it is able to see a greater amount of charge in a more focused field of view, canceling out the reduction in strength caused by increasing the distance between the point and the plate. My issue is that I want to be able to derive this relationship for myself using calculus and I when doing it by hand, I always arrive at a relationship that reduces the strength of the electric field as the distance increases.

I eventually found a [paper online](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/mchutchon/chargedPlanes.pdf) that derives the property of uniformity, but it has a step when evaluating an improper integral that makes no sense to me:

$$
\begin{align}
E_P &= \frac{\sigma r}{4\pi\epsilon} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2 + r^2)^{3/2}} \; dx \; dy \\
&= \frac{\sigma r}{4\pi\epsilon} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2}{(y^2 + r^2)^{3/2}} \; dy \tag{1} \\
&= \frac{\sigma r}{4\pi\epsilon} \frac{2\pi}{r} \tag{2} \\
&= \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon}
\end{align}
$$

What happened between lines (1) and (2)? When I did it by hand, I ended up with,
$$
\frac{\sigma r}{4\pi\epsilon} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2}{(y^2 + r^2)^{3/2}} \; dy
=
\frac{\sigma r}{4\pi\epsilon} \frac{4}{r^2}
=
\frac{4\sigma}{r\pi\epsilon}
$$

I checked this result with Maxima and [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F(a%5E2%2Bx%5E2)%5E(3%2F2)+from+-oo+to+oo,+a%3E0), and they both confirm my answer. What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the transition from the line above (1) to line (1). Based on my calculation, line (1) should be $$E_P =  \frac{\sigma r}{4 \pi \epsilon} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {2}{(r^2 + y^2)}  dy  $$

This gives the appropriate result in line (2) and the final answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if I can notify the maintainer of the document to fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, something seems to be mixed up. I'd always integrate this in a different way:
$$\begin{align} 
E_P&=&\frac{r \sigma}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}x\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}y \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+r^2}^3}\\
&=&\frac{r \sigma}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\int_{0}^\infty2\pi \rho\mathrm{d}\rho \frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho^2+r^2}^3}\\
&=&\frac{r \sigma}{2 \epsilon_0}\int_{0}^\infty  \frac{\rho\mathrm{d}\rho}{\sqrt{\rho^2+r^2}^3}\\
&=&\frac{r \sigma}{2 \epsilon_0} \frac{1}{r}\\
&=&\frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_0} 
\end{align} $$
i.e. using symmetry again and changing to cylindrical coordinates.